# WiX - Restart service after modification of the installed product

Tags: service, wix, installation

I'm writing a MSI which installs a windows service and adds some DLLs which the service uses. Those DLLs are features which can be added or removed using the installer.

After a user modifies the installed product(eq. add a new feature), windows service needs to be restarted. Is there a more elegant way of doing so in WiX 3.5 other than calling a custom action which would restart the service?

This is how I'm starting the service.

```
<ServiceControl Id="StartService" Name="MyService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall"  Wait="yes" />
```

EDIT:
Here's the complete component code. Disregard the ids.

```
<Component Id="MyService" Guid="GUID">
     <File Id="MyService"
      Source="$(var.BuildDestination)/$(var.NameSpacePrefix).MyService.exe"
      KeyPath="yes"
      >
</File>
<RemoveFile Id='AppConfigFile' On='uninstall' Name='MyService.exe.Config' />
<User xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
         Id="ServiceAccount"
         CreateUser="no"
         FailIfExists="no"
         RemoveOnUninstall="no"
         UpdateIfExists="yes"
         Disabled="no"
         LogonAsService="yes"
         Name="[ACCOUNT]"
         Password="[PASSWORD]" />
<ServiceInstall
          Id="MyService"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Vital="yes"
          Name="MyService"
          DisplayName="MyService"
          Description="MyService"
          Start="auto"
          Account="[ACCOUNT]"
          Password="[PASSWORD]"
          ErrorControl="ignore"
          Interactive="no">
</ServiceInstall>
<ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                Name="MyService"
                Start="install"
                Stop="both"
                Remove="both"
                Wait="yes"
                >
</ServiceControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the state of the service feature(feature which installs and starts the service) wasn't updated, the service itself wasn't stopped and started too.
I've solved the issue by adding ServiceControl to all components which are separate features.

```
<Component Id="Modules1" Guid="GUID">
<File Id="Modules.1" Source="$(var.BuildDestination)/$(var.NameSpacePrefix)Modules.1.dll" KeyPath="yes">
</File>
<ServiceControl Id="StartService1"
               Name="MyService"
               Start="install"
               Stop="both"
               Wait="yes"
                >
</ServiceControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

```
<Component Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
    <File           Source      ="MyService.exe"
                    KeyPath     ="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id          ="MyService.exe"
                    Name        ="My Service"
                    Account     ="LocalSystem"
                    Start       ="auto"
                    ErrorControl="normal"
                    Interactive ="no"
                    Type        ="ownProcess"
                    Description ="My service does stuff."/>
    <ServiceControl Id          ="MyService.exe"
                    Name        ="My Service"
                    Start       ="install"
                    Stop        ="both"
                    Remove      ="both"
                    Wait        ="no"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't do the trick for me. I've added the complete component code in the original post.

Comment: What do you see in the Event Viewer under Windows Logs, Application, where Source is wither MsiInstaller or MyService?

Comment: What happens if you change `ErrorControl` to `"normal"` or `"critical"`?  This may provide more information.

Comment: I've changed the ErrorControl to critical. Install log `MSI (s) (54:58) [04:49:25:877]: Doing action: StopServices
MSI (s) (54:58) [04:49:25:877]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 4:49:25: StopServices. Stopping services
Action start 4:49:25: StopServices.
Action ended 4:49:25: StopServices. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (54:58) [04:49:25:880]: Doing action: DeleteServices
MSI (s) (54:58) [04:49:25:880]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 4:49:25: DeleteServices. Deleting services
Action start 4:49:25: DeleteServices.
Action ended 4:49:25: DeleteServices. Return value 1.`

Comment: However, in the Event Viewer there is no entry related to the starting/stopping of the MyService

Comment: Just to be clear, the service is a separate feature which is not being changed in this scenario. Could this be the reason why installer is not restarting the service?

Comment: If the service file is not being replaced, the component won't execute because nothing has changed.  However, you'd expect an error when the MSI tried to replace DLL files in use by the service.  What if you add all files related to the service to the same component as the service?  That will execute the component when any one of those DLLs changes.