# WiX - Modify existing product - remove a file after a feature is deselected

Tags: wix

My installer adds a windows service and DLLs which the service uses. Those DLLs are features which can be added or removed using the installer.

When once installed feature is removed using the change dialog, a corresponding DLL is not removed, and is still present in the system. This is not the expected behavior - I would like for the DLL to be removed after a feature is deselected.

Here's how features are defined

```
  <Feature Id="Modules" Title="Modules" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" 
       Display="expand" AllowAdvertise='no' InstallDefault='local' Absent='disallow'>
<ComponentRef Id="MyModules" />
<Feature Id="Feature1" Title="F1" Level="0" ConfigurableDirectory="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR">
  <Condition Level="1">Some condition</Condition>
  <ComponentRef Id="Module1" />
</Feature>

<Component Id="Module1" Guid="GUID">
<File Id="File.Module1" Source="$(var.BuildDestination)/$(var.NameSpacePrefix).Module1.dll">
</File>
```

Comment: Perhaps the file is in use, preventing it from being removed?

Comment: @WimCoenen The service is using the file(DLL) but it should be stopped during the install. `<ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                    Name="MyService"
                    Start="install"
                    Stop="both"
                    Remove="both"
                    Wait="yes"
                    />`

Comment: Try creating a verbose log and search for InstallValidate action to see why the DLL is not uninstalled: http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/

Comment: @CosminPirvu It seems that the service which is using the DLL is not being stopped [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066804/wix-restart-service-after-modification-of-the-installed-product/9071723#comment11396557_9071723)

Comment: This cannot be seen from the log `Action start: InstallValidate. MSI Feature: Feature; Installed: Local; Request: Null; Action: Null
MSI (s) Component: Modules.1; Installed: Local; Request: Null; Action: Null; Client State: Local
Action ended: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
MSI (s) Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
MSI (s) Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText 
Action RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
Action RemoveExistingProducts.
Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall
Action ended RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 0.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that that the issue was caused by the feature conditions which were not met during the Change process.
After removing the

```
<Condition Level="1">Some condition</Condition>
```

Installer removed obsolete DLLs without issues.